When i am trying to run the stable diffusion i am getting error 128 of the github
While i am running webui.sh in my terminal i am getting error code 128.
enter image description here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/ASUS/stablediff/stable-diffusion-webui/launch.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/ASUS/stablediff/stable-diffusion-webui/launch.py", line 39, in main
    prepare_environment()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/ASUS/stablediff/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/launch_utils.py", line 411, in prepare_environment
    git_clone(stable_diffusion_repo, repo_dir('stable-diffusion-stability-ai'), "Stable Diffusion", stable_diffusion_commit_hash)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/ASUS/stablediff/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/launch_utils.py", line 191, in git_clone
    run(f'"{git}" clone --config core.filemode=false "{url}" "{dir}"', f"Cloning {name} into {dir}...", f"Couldn't clone {name}", live=True)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/ASUS/stablediff/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/launch_utils.py", line 115, in run
    raise RuntimeError("\n".join(error_bits))
RuntimeError: Couldn't clone Stable Diffusion.
Command: "git" clone --config core.filemode=false "https://github.com/Stability-AI/stablediffusion.git" "/mnt/c/Users/ASUS/stablediff/stable-diffusion-webui/repositories/stable-diffusion-stability-ai"
Error code: 128

I am trying to run stable-diffusion-webui in my pc i am using win11 with wsl of Ubuntu.
